# What is meant by the term "web root"?

Tags: security, web-applications, directory, webserver, directory-structure

I have set up my own AMP stack on my local machine and am playing around with web application development. I am researching about various best practices is secure application development, and I see constant references to the term "web root"

For example:

> Make sure you store the file outside of the web root

I more or less understand, however, I am slightly confused. Consider the WebServer directory in OS X:

```
/Library
|
|--WebServer
   |
   |--CGI-Executables
   |
   |--share
   |
   |--Documents
      |--index.html.en
      |--MyWebApp
         |
         |--myFile1.html
         |--myFile2.js
         |--myFile3.php
```

The term *seems* to suggest that the web root is at the `MyWebApp` directory. However, wouldn't anything under 'Documents' be visible, or even anything under `WebServer`. Maybe not, because when I remove `index.html.en` and navigate to localhost/ in my browser, I get a `403` error.

What is meant by the "web root"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web root is the first directory can be accesible by the web. Usually is called /public_html. You can define directories at the same level or upper with data that is used in your website (e.g. images, cache memory...).